# How can I add a single SAS drive to a Perc H700 on Dell R310 server WITHOUT loosing the data on it?

Tags: linux, dell, sas, dell-perc, h700

On a Dell R310 server with Perc H700 RAID controller.

I have 1 virtual disk configured as Raid 1 but with only 1 physical SAS disk attached and the other missing. This virtual disk has been configured with fresh CentOS 6.9 and boots normally.

I now have another physical SAS disk containing some recovered data. Can I create a second virtual disk again containing only 1 disk WITHOUT loosing the data on it and then simply mount it in the OS? I am afraid it will initalize and erase the disk if I do that. How can this be accomplished? We don't have other options for reading the SAS drive. I am not able to find any guides relating to this scenario.

Reading the manual it seems I should be able to create a VD and then NOT initialize it. Would this make it accessible to the OS (f.ex. like would it allow linux to create a /dev/sdX device)?

Answer (score 0):

> another physical SAS disk containing some recovered data

Was this disk "behind" a PERC RAID controller in its original configuration when the data was written to it?
If so, and if it was configured as a RAID0 (or in a 2-disk RAID1), then the VD creation without initialization option *should* work.

If the disk was originally connected to a SAS HBA (non-RAID), then this likely won't work quite as well for recovering the data since the H700 does not support pass-through mode.

When you create a new virtual disk on the added drive, *some* data (metadata) *will* be written to the beginning of the drive. If the disk was originally non-RAID, then this will be overwriting some or all of the disk's partition table, and potentially even some beginning sectors of the actual partition / data.

> We don't have other options for reading the SAS drive

You could always purchase an LSI 9207-8i or similar internal 6Gbps SAS HBA if you want to really be safe - they're quite inexpensive too, now that 12Gbps SAS is mainstream.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The disk with the recovered data was a blank disk given to the recovery company to put the recovered data on. I don't think it has any RAID info on it because if I install it and boot up the PERC controller says nothing (otherwise it should ask to import or clear foreign config, right?). But I will call the recovery company and find out for sure.  We might go with the LSI option you mentioned to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Full man page for MegaCLI is given below:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170626231838/https://www.dokterlinux.id/hardware-raid-setup-using-megacli-on-linux/

The command to pop a physical drive into the chassis and flip it into online state is:

```
# MegaCli -PDOnline -PhysDrv [E:S] -aN
```